# JPA: How to load original entity in transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to calculate the modifications in an entity before updating it.

1. display HTML form
2. on submit:

   1. start transaction
   2. load entity
   3. apply form data to entity
   4. calculate changes
   5. persist entity

Steps 2.1 through 2.3 are managed through my MVC framework (Spring MVC) so I never actually have a reference to the original entity without the changes.

So what I'm currently trying to do is the following:

```
// transaction is already started
public Modifications store(Entity updated) {
    Entity original = entityManager.find(Entity.class, updated.getId());
    Modifications mods = calculateModifications(original, updated);
    entityManager.merge(updated);
    return mods;
}
```

But unfortunately the entity I receive from the entity manager is the same (read `==`) as the updated one.

Here's the question: How do I force the entity manager to load the entity again from the database without detaching my updated entity?

I am using Hibernate as my persistence provider, but I would like to keep this provider agnostic as much as possible.

Comment: To me, the problem is where you start the transaction. It should be 1. load entity, 2. apply form data to entity, 3. start transaction. The transaction should be started by the service layer, and not by the UI layer. BTW, with the current situation, you need to explicitely rollback the transaction in case of a validation error, alse the entity populated from the request parameters will be persisted.

Comment: Good thought, I totally agree. Actually I have no idea why this is running in a transaction... :-) Maybe I'll have to configure my `OpenViewInEntityManagerFilter`, because my MVC controller methods really shouldn't run in a transaction. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an SO answer which is similar to your question [Hibernate: comparing current & previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183013/hibernate-comparing-current-previous-record)

Use method `evict` to remove old instance from the session cache then check `calculateModifications` for updates with new one which you get from method `find`

Comment: Exactly. With your query against the id you just get the modified entity from the PersistenceContext.

Comment: Eviction works, although this is not what I did in the end. I completely removed transactionality from my views so the controller method would not run in a transaction anymore. Hence there's no need to evict the entity anymore.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can use `detach` if `EntityManager` used by you. The code like below:

```
entityManager.detach(newOne);
Order oldOne = orderRepository.findById(orderId);
// compare newOne and oldOne
...
```