# ManyToOne relationship is always null when finding entity in the same transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a ConversationEntity with a ManyToOne relationship with ModeratorEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CONVERSATIONS")
public class ConversationEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    private Integer moderatorId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="moderatorId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private ModeratorEntity moderator;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="MODERATORS")
public class ModeratorEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    private Integer name;
}
```

And a service class with a transactional method that first of all saves the ModeratorEntity and after that the ConversationEntity with the moderatorId previously created

```
    @Transactional
    public void doStuff(Moderator moderator, Integer conversationId) {
        Integer moderatorId = moderatorService.save(moderator);
        Integer conversationId = conversationService.save(conversationId, moderatorId);

        //do other stuff

        Conversation conversation = conversationService.findById(conversationId);
    }
```

When I'm trying to find the ConversationEntity by the id in the same transaction, a few lines below, I'm getting the ConversationEntity with the field moderatorId set but with the ModeratorEntity object = null.

If I do this outside the transaction I'm getting the ModeratorEntity object properly set.

I tried using saveAndFlush in ModeratorRepository and ConversationRepository and set FetchType.EAGER in the ManyToOne relationship but none of them worked

Comment: Do you think that the FK field should be `insertable=false, updatable=false`

Comment: There is no problem with that. The thing is why the repository is returning a not-null id but a null related entity if I find in the same transaction

Comment: @AlejandroCuervo Maybe instead of `name="moderatorId"` you should use `name="moderator_id"`?

Comment: The mapping with database fields are correct. I guess it should be some trouble with the transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many questions about similar problems. For example [@Transactional in bidirectional relation with Spring Data returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110830/transactional-in-bidirectional-relation-with-spring-data-returns-null) and [Hibernate: comparing current & previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183013/hibernate-comparing-current-previous-record).

As long as you are within a single transaction you'll always get the same instance and no data is actually loaded from the database. And since (it seems at least) you never set the reference to the `ModeratorEntity` it stays `null`.

Once you are in a new transaction the database gets accessed and JPA populates a new instance, now including a `ModeratorEntity` reference.

The possible fixes therefore are:

- Instead of an id let `moderatorService.save` return an entity and set that in the `Conversation`. You might as well drop the `moderatorId`. This is the idiomatic way to do things with JPA.
- Perform the query in a separate transaction. Springs [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) might come in handy. While this does work it causes JPA internals to bleed into your application which I recommend to avoid.

Comment: Setting moderatorEntity in ConversationEntity before saving works for me!!! Thx